# Not able to load data files in Cassandra using sstableloader

Tags: cassandra

I have following set of sstable files in cassandra version 1.0.12

```
column_data-hd-\<some-number\>-Data.db
column_data-hd-\<some-number\>-Digest.sha1
column_data-hd-\<some-number\>-Index.db
column_data-hd-\<some-number\>-Filter.db
column_data-hd-\<some-number\>-Statistics.db
```

I am trying to load these sstable files into cassandra version 1.1.0 using sstableloader shows me below error.

Skipping file column_data-hd--Data.db: column family keyspace-name.hd does't exists
Here there is no file like keyspace-name.hd

Does not work with nodetool upgradesstables as well

```
sstableloader -d \[hostname\] \[dir_keyspace/columnFamily\]
```

Here I have created keyspace and columnfamily

Same does not work with cassandra version 1.2.9

Loading these into diff cluster of cassandra version 1.0.12 using nodetool refresh works fine

Steps I follow

1. Create keyspace and column family
2. Copy sstable files under /keyspace/columnfamily
3. run sstableload / nodetool upgradesstables

Comment: Are you using sstableloader from 1.1.0 or 1.0.12? You should use the 1.0.12 version, which will read and stream the data into 1.1.0. That's what I can think of straight away. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Since I am upgrading to 1.1.0, I am using sstableloader from 1.1.0 and data files copied from 1.0.12

Answer (score 0):

On the more recent versions of SSTableLoader, when using the command the name of the folder you are loading from is used by it to determine the keyspace / tablename. If the older version of the loader followed that same pattern then the name of the folder structure above the file matters, e.g. it should be something like:

```
/some/path/of/yours/keyspace/table/<your files>
```

Of course, we also strongly recommend that you upgrade as soon as possible, as far as possible. It might be that you are using thrift and can not get to Cassandra 4, but at least get to the latest 3.11 as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi Andrew, the folder from where I am running sstableloader is correct, it is able to find files but skipping it.
The purpose is to upgrade to latest version of cassandra, since its not possible to directly upgrade from 1.x to latest version, we are incrementally upgrading to intermediate versions

Answer (score 0):

It worked on ver 1.1.0 by appending all files with keyspace name like below

**keyspaceName-**column_data-hd-<some-number>-Data.db